# Load DB data(to Rest API) through postman

Tags: sql, rest, postman

We have been using postman for our Rest API testing but to make it more of an e2e data driven tool, we have a requirement to:
- Make postman grab data from our database and feed it to the API calls
- Run some api calls based on that data
- Query DB again to check the sanity of the data after REST POST requests for example

I know postman is for client side interactions. Is there a way to make postman to talk to DB somehow? I have came across "[volos-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/volos-mysql#database-connection-profile)" and "[dreamFactory](http://blog.dreamfactory.com/add-a-rest-api-to-any-sql-db-in-minutes)" but problem is how to load an external module inside postman script?

Comment: as for as I know unhappily there is no way to make your request with postman :(

Comment: I am looking at the same kind of thing. What I think I will end up doing is create a java class which runs postman collections via the newman module (allows to run postman collections via command line so I assume I can use java runtime exec for that). This java class can then do whatever you want to the database, feed it, delete it, query stuff, etc.